# Appcelerator : animate the backgroundColor of a listview item

Tags: ios, listview, appcelerator, listviewitem, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to animate the **backgroundColor** property of a **listview** **item** children.

This is the code

```
var itemToUpdate = myListView.getSections();
itemToUpdate = itemToUpdate[0].getItemAt(myPos);
//itemToUpdate.child_to_update.backgroundColor = myColor; //this works , but without animation
itemToUpdate.child_to_update.animate({
    backgroundColor : myColor,
    duration : 450
});
myListView.sections[0].updateItemAt(myPos , itemToUpdate);
```

Comment: Please try to formulate your question as a question and make sure your code is complete. `catToUpdate` is not defined e.g.

Comment: sorry , catToUpdate -> itemToUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [Ti.UI.ListSection.getItemAt()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListSection-method-getItemAt) gets you a [ListDataItem](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/ListDataItem). This object does not hold references to the actual views, but to the data used to generated the views using the ListView [ItemTemplates](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/ItemTemplate) you have defined. This is great for performance, but it means you cannot directly manipulate the views and use a method like `animate()`.

**TL;DR** What you want is not possible using ListView. Consider using TableView instead.

Comment: I figured it was due to this. I prefer the performance, so no animation for now. Thank you